# Pass JavaScript variable to Apex Controller

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I need help. I received the below error:

```
LWC1503: "getItemApprove" is not a known adapter. (29:11)
```

I am trying to pass ApprovalId from js to the apex class.
Here is the Apex code

```
public with sharing class toApproved {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static list<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> getItemApprove(id ActorId){
    return[select ProcessInstance.TargetObject.name, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.name, ActorId, Actor.name from ProcessInstanceWorkitem
    where ActorId = :ActorId
    order by CreatedDate limit 100];
}}
```

Here is the js code

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import toApproved from '@salesforce/apex/toApproved.getItemApprove';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';

const columns = [
    {label: 'Related to', fieldName:'Object', type:'url', typeAttributes:{
        label:{fieldName:'recordName'},target:'_blank'}
    },

    {label: 'Submitted By', fieldName:'CreatedBy', type:'url', typeAttributes:{
        label:{fieldName:'createdByName'},target:'_blank'}
    },

    {label: 'Date Submitted', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date',typeAttributes:{
        day:'numeric',month:'short',year:'numeric',hour:'2-digit',minute:'2-digit',second:'2-digit',hour12:true}
    },

    {label: 'Approver Name', fieldName: 'ApprovedBy', type: 'url', typeAttributes:{
        label:{fieldName:'ApprovarName'}, target:'_blank'}
    }
];

export default class ToApproved extends LightningElement {
    ApprovarId= Id;
    availableItems;
    error;
    columns = columns;

    @wire(getItemApprove,{ActorId: '$ApprovarId'}) 
    ProcessInstanceWorkitem;

    @wire (toApproved)
    wiredAccount({error,data}){
        if(data){
            let tempRecs = [];
            data.forEach((record)=>{
                let tempRec = Object.assign({},record);

                //Name & target object id
                var objDes = JSON.stringify(tempRec.ProcessInstance.TargetObject);
                var finalObject = JSON.parse(objDes);
                tempRec.Object = '/'+tempRec.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId;
                tempRec.recordName = finalObject.Name;

                //Name & created/submitted user id
                var createduser = JSON.stringify(tempRec.CreatedBy);
                var finalData = JSON.parse(createduser);
                tempRec.CreatedBy = '/'+tempRec.CreatedById;
                tempRec.createdByName = finalData.Name;

                //Name and approverid
                var approvar = JSON.stringify(tempRec.Actor);
                var finalApprovar = JSON.parse(approvar);
                tempRec.ApprovedBy = '/'+finalApprovar.name;
                tempRec.ApprovarName = tempRec.Actor.Name;

                tempRecs.push(tempRec);
            });
            this.availableItems = tempRecs;
            this.error = undefined;

        }else if(error){
            this.error = error;
            this.availableItems = undefined;
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import toApproved from '@salesforce/apex/toApproved.getItemApprove';
```

...

```
@wire(getItemApprove,{ActorId: '$ApprovarId'}) 
ProcessInstanceWorkitem;

@wire (toApproved)
wiredAccount({error,data}){
```

You imported the method as `toApproved`, so that's the name you need to use (or, change it to `getItemApprove`). Make sure that the names agree with each other.